# How to find the change in time over a given distance, without constant acceleration or velocity?

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

I'm working on a problem that essentially is trying to calculate the maximum velocity and time it would take, for one to fall through a friction-less hole from Chicago to Rome.

I have derived a function with respect to distance that calculates the acceleration at any point x in the tube. Integrating this from x=0 to the center point of the hole, which in this case happens to be x=3633501, gives me my maximum velocity. However, I am at a loss for how to calculate the time it would take to get to the center of the tunnel, which I would then double to get the overall trip time.

The formula for acceleration with respect to position is as follows:

$$a(x) = 1.5404 \cdot 10^{-6}\cdot \sqrt{3.1272 \cdot 10^{13}+x^2-7267002x}\cdot \sin\left(\arctan(\frac{2968886}{\sqrt{2.24584 \cdot 10^{13}+x^2-7627002x}})\right)$$

If anyone has any idea where to go from here to calculate time, it would be greatly appreciated. I can supply any other info upon request, I'm just not sure what is important to include here and what isn't.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn’t acceleration just be the gravity constant since you’re falling?

Comment: @JosephEck no, since the effective gravitational force becomes smaller as you are falling, the acceleration decreases. Additionally, the hole is not directly into the core of the earth, so the only the horizontal component of gravitational force needs to be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(\arctan(x))=\frac x{1+x^2}$ will get rid of the trig functions.  After that I suspect you are in for numerical integration.

Answer (score 1):

If you use conservation of energy, you can get the velocity as a function of distance along the tube. Suppose the length of the tube is $2L$, and we set the coordinate system such as $x=0$ is at the center of the tube. That point is at a distance $r_{min}=\sqrt{R^2-L^2}$ from the center of the Earth of radius $R$. Conservation of energy says:
$$\frac{GMm}{R}=\frac{GM_im}{r}+\frac{mv^2}{2}$$
$M_i$ is the mass of the Earth that is inside the radius $r$
$$M_i=M\frac{r^3}{R^3}$$
All you need is now the relationship between $r$ and $x$
$$r^2=r_{min}^2+x^2=R^2-L^2+x^2$$

If I did not do any mistakes, you get $$v^2(x)=2GM\frac{L^2-x^2}{R^3}$$
To get time
$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ or $dt=\frac{dx}{v}$, so
$$T=\int_{-L}^{L}\frac{dx}{v(x)}$$